# calculating the distance between 2 points openCV c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv

Basically i have to figure out whether the label on on object is straight. I have an edge image of the object. I would like to calculate the distance between the 2 edges on either side in a single row. 
My algorithm involves iterating through a row until a white pixel is found. Then calculating the number of black pixels until the next white is found. However when i run the code the answer is always zero.

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
{

    int num = nms_result.at<int>(i,100);
    //cout <<num<<endl;
    if(num > 0) { 
               stage2 = true;
    }

    if (stage2 ==true)
        counter4++;
    { 

        int num2 = nms_result.at<int>(i,100);
        ;

        if ((num2 < 1) && (counter4 >=1 )) {
                counter2++;
        }       

                else counter4 = 0;

    }


    }
```

I have tried a lot of things but none seem to work.

Comment: can't need 10 reputation to post images

Answer (score 0):

Problem number 1: If I'm reading your code right, 'num' and 'num2' are always the same, since they're in the same loop.

Problem number 2: What's the output here? a little hard to tell with your formatting. Consider using some indentations with your nested ifs.

Comment: num1 and num2 are the same. I know that, i recalculate it for debugging purpoeses. The output is counter2. counter4 is just a check.

Comment: In your second if statement, you use a one liner to increment counter4. Then, you have brackets to do the if tests to increment counter2. Maybe the code in brackets for counter2 is never running because the compiler is terminating the if statement after your one-liner.

Comment: Also, one more thing, are you using a binary image? Just 1's for white and 0's for black? Or is this int/float?